# Unable to connect to server: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, pgadmin

I just did a fresh installation of `postgres 13` on my `windows 10 64 bit` and when I open the `pgadmin 4` there are not servers listed on the servers list on left handside. When I try to add a server I get `Unable to connect to server:  FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist`

[image]

the credentials I am using here are the credentials I entered while installing postgres but I have tried a bunch of other creds as well like postgres and blank, postgres and postgres but the behavior is same.

In my `pg_hba.conf` file the value of method is already set to `trust` instead of `md5` so I have not made any changes to that file. I have tried restarting the postgres service as well but that didnt help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message does not match your screen shot. In the screen shot you are using user(role) `admin` and the error message says role `postgres`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Whether I enter `admin` or `postgres` the behavior is same. `FATAL: role "some username" does not exist`

Comment: Did you install using the EDB installer from here [Windows](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)? Can you connect using `psql`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, thats where I got the installer from and I get the same error when I try to connect through psql as well

Comment: Well the EDB installer installs as the postgres user which means there should be a postgres role. Have no idea why that would not be the case. Do you have only one instance of Postgres installed on this machine? If so I would uninstall Postgres and then reinstall.

Comment: Yes, I only have one instance of postgres on this machine infact, this is the very first time I am installing postgres. And thanks, thats what I in mind as well to try to reinstall it.